# Sanskrit language learning resources and tools

Tags: resource-request, sanskrit

What are some free and open-source online (or offline) Sanskrit learning resources and tools?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. You are asking for different types of resources all at once: dictionaries, thesauruses, databases & search engines, translation software, TTS engines. This makes your question too broad. Could you please split it up into one question (i.e. one post) per type of resource?

Comment: @Tsundoku Unlike other languages, Sanskrit language resources are not easily available. Therefore, all the different resources does not make an extensive list.

Comment: @Tsundoku I have edited my question.